# Log aggregator/monitoring tool

Tags: logging, visualization, apache-servicemix

I've an architecture with clustered servicemixes. Inside every instance I've a few files with logs containing all requests/responses in xml before and after xslt transformations, cause we're working on ESB. I'm working with analitycs and testers and I would like to use some tools to aggregate this files and show them through a browser. I saw a very good tool to view logs inside hawtIo, but I would like to configue tool ONLY to monitor logs. Any suggestions? Or should I write it alone or teach others how to use grep and tail commands ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have different tools available, if you just want to use the logfiles you can go with a plain ELK stack (Elasticsearch LogStash and Kibana) or as you use servicemix install parts of this stack on your servers, by using the karaf-decanter tools.

For example just do the following:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.karaf.decanter/apache-karaf-decanter/1.0.0/xml/features

feature:install decanter-collector-log
feature:install decanter-collector-jmx
feature:install decanter-appender-elasticsearch
feature:install elasticsearch
```

for details on karaf-decanter take a look at the [official documentation](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/decanter/latest-1/index.html)